# pg_config - how to change postgres versions

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, config

By default I had postgres 10 versions on my two ubuntu 14 machines, but I installed postgres 9.6 on the two of them.

But on one of them pg_config give me:

```
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.6.6
```

And the other:

```
VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.1
```

They have the same libpq-dev packages in:

```
dpkg -l | grep libpq-dev

libpq-dev  10.1-1.pgdg14.04+1  amd64 header files for libpq5 (PostgreSQL library)
```

So I was wondering is there a way for me to change the version installed that it gives me postgres 9.6 instead of postgres 10.01? Maybe using the pg_config file?

Tnx,
Tom

update:
on the instance that still shows postgres 10, this is the result(which shows that it is not installed):

```
ii  pgdg-keyring                         2017.3                                     all          keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgresql-9.6                       9.6.6-1.pgdg14.04+1                        amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.6 server
ii  postgresql-client-9.6                9.6.6-1.pgdg14.04+1                        amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.6
ii  postgresql-client-common             189.pgdg14.04+1                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                    189.pgdg14.04+1                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.6               9.6.6-1.pgdg14.04+1                        amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
```

Comment: Uninstall Postgres 10, then install Postgres 9.6

Comment: I did that, postgres 10 is not installed, but the config_pg stil still points to it!

Comment: That must be some artifact caused by the weird way the Debian packages are built. In standard PostgreSQL, `pg_config` is an executable, no shell script. You might ask the packagers...

Comment: I'm working on ubuntu 14, and on it the pg_config is a bash script that has some logic in it...where it looks for the postgres-server-dev-XY package first - I installed the postgres-server-dev-9.6 package and then the pg_config command returned postgres 9.6 installed (not postgres 10). That was a quick solution - I will checkout if there is a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but let me leave some observations here. When you install PostgreSQL,it comes with the `pg_config` utility.Since you installed two versions, you have two `pg_config` utlities.When you run `pg_config` in your terminal you might get say PostgreSQL VERSION 9 instead of PostgreSQL VERSION 10 or vice versa. When you run, `sudo find / -name pg_config`, two directories of the `pg_config` will be shown in your terminal. Usually, the first listed directory of `pg_config` is the default for `pg_config` command. When you run the `pg_config` by specifying its absolute path of the first or the second directory, for example `/usr/lib/postgresql/pg_config --version` it gives your first or your second installed version.

Answer (score 0):

duplicated: [pg_config shows 9.4 instead of 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143046/pg-config-shows-9-4-instead-of-9-3/43403193)

On: Debian, Ubuntu

the *bash* /usr/bin/pg_config is setup to look and get the latest */usr/lib/postgresql/*/pg_config --version* available

A fast solution, NOT elegant and weak, could be to update it as follow.
Then update env as, e.g.:

```
export FORCE_PGCONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/pg_config
```

**/usr/bin/pg_config** (updated) :

```
PGBINROOT="/usr/lib/postgresql/"
#redhat# PGBINROOT="/usr/pgsql-"
# user edit :
if [ -n "$FORCE_PGCONFIG" ]; then
    # up to you to set it properly...
    LATEST_SERVER_DEV="$FORCE_PGCONFIG";
else
    LATEST_SERVER_DEV=`ls -v $PGBINROOT*/bin/pg_config 2>/dev/null|tail -n1`;
fi
# end user edit ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if [ -n "$LATEST_SERVER_DEV" ]; then
    exec "$LATEST_SERVER_DEV" "$@"
else
    if [ -x /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev "$@"
    else
    echo "You need to install postgresql-server-dev-NN for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application." >&2
    exit 1
    fi
fi
```